# How can i copy this hidden value in field from my first page and post in my 2nd page?

Tags: php, forms

how can i get the value from first page and post it in the second page? so if you click the button you will be forwarded to sample.com/VALUE

first page

```php
<form action="<?php echo $link.$post_data['post_name']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="link1" value="<?php echo $_GET['go']; ?>">
<input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" value="Get Your Link">
</form>
```

2nd page

```php
<form id="3" action="http://sample.com/" method="post" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
<center><input type="image" src="/Button-1.png" form="3" type="submit" value="submit"></center>
</form>
```

Comment: In the 2nd page execute this: var_dump($_POST);

Comment: with "so if you click the button you will be forwarded to sample.com/VALUE" you mean the button in the second page?

Comment: Side note: Using images for inputs won't work. Use JS/Ajax for this type of method to work. PHP can't handle it alone. Meaning, it won't pass any GET/POST/REQUEST/SESSION/FILES array.

Comment: var dump post result 
array(1) { ["link1"]=> string(5) "45456" }

@MannyRamirez

Comment: yes if you click the button it will be forwarded to sample.com/45456 as dump post result @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand very well but how about this ?

```
<form action="http://sample.com/<?=$_POST['link1'];?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="link1" value="<?=$_GET['go'];?>">
<input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" value="Get Your Link">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

i added the `<?php echo $_POST['link1']; ?>` in the 2nd url

```
<form id="3" action="http://sample.com/<?php echo $_POST['link1']; ?>" method="post" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
```

and it works now thanks guys for helping

Comment: Isn't that what [the other guy said/posted?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58966229/1415724)